# php7.2-fpm is not starting anymore

Tags: php

I have installed and in use both *php7.0-fpm* and *php7.2-fpm* on a **Ubuntu 14.04 Server**. I installed php7.2-fpm in the morning and it was working fine, the applications were running successfully. Then in the evening I have manually restarted php7.2-fpm, but this seems to have broken something. I used the command :

```
sudo service php7.2-fpm restart
```

The proces has stopped, but cannot be started anymore. When I try to start it seems to work:

```
php7.2-fpm start/running, process 31336
```

But when I check with:

```
sudo service php7.2-fpm status
```

The result is:

```
php7.2-fpm stop/waiting
```

There is also no *php7.2-fpm.sock* file anymore.

There is nothing in the php7.2 logs, so I have no idea what can be wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out *php7.2-fpm* was listening to *php7.0-fpm.sock*. I have no idea how that value was changed,but I changed it to *php7.2-fpm.sock* and it's working now.

The configuration is set in:

```
/etc/php/7.2/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
```